# asix driver becomes unresponsive after a while

Tags: power-management, acpi

My ethernet adapter goes dead every once in a while, and I am trying to debug. I am using factory drivers with kernel `4.4.126-48-default` on OpenSUSE Leap 42.3
.
Here are the symptomps,

1. The USB ethernet adapter stops working, no lights, unplug-replug doesn’t work, not messages in dmesg about when I unplug-replug. Needs reboot. dmesg has a bunch of errors like this,

.

```
[ 1828.505237] asix 1-4:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Failed to enable software MII access                                                                            
[ 1838.505218] asix 1-4:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Failed to enable hardware MII access                                                                            
[ 1843.505221] asix 1-4:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Failed to enable software MII access                                                                            
[ 1853.505201] asix 1-4:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Failed to enable hardware MII access                                                                            
[ 1858.505066] asix 1-4:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Failed to enable software MII access                                                                            
[ 1868.505167] asix 1-4:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Failed to enable hardware MII access
```

2. trying `# modprobe -rf asix` (asix module has no dependants) just hangs without any output.
3. `# powertop` also hangs on initialization.
4. `# killall upower` seem to solve the problem. (After that the `rmmod` and `powertop` commands work, and reloading the module make the ethernet adapter work.

I’d like to fix this issue, which I assume is related to power modules, but not sure how to fix.
​

Answer (score 0):

-the Ethernet USB adapter can also be described as a radio frequency transceiver.  It requires significant power in order to transmit a signal to the WiFi modem that is located nearby.  The integrated circuit that accomplishes this task will get warm, and is subject to overheating.  I recently had a similar issue with the "WLAN 11g USB Adapter" that is plugged into the back of my older HP Compaq desktop computer.  The problem was solved by removing the plastic cover from the USB plug in, which allows the internal parts to cool better, as they are exposed to fresh air.  My next step would be to put some sort of fan back there, but so far, this has not been necessary.  My WiFi internet connection is now stable for an hour or so, which is as long as I ever stay at the computer, at one sitting.